# Make Zend\Debug\Debug::dump() only dump in development mode?

Tags: zend-framework2

For quick debugging I prefer `Zend\Debug\Debug::dump()`. The problem: Sometimes I forget to remove old dump statements and they make it into production.

It would be great if `Debug::dump()` only printed something, when I’m in [development mode](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-development-mode).

Is there any elegant way to achieve this without having to transform Zend\Debug\Debug into a service? I like the plain and simple static method call. Probably through setting an env var when enabling dev mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/public/.htaccess` add this code. `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"`

In your `/public/index.php` file

```
/**
 * Set global ENV. Used for debugging
 */
if (isset($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV']) && $_SERVER["APPLICATION_ENV"] === 'development') {
    define("APP_ENV", 'development');
} else {
    define("APP_ENV", "production");
}

/**
 * Set default php.ini settings.
 *
 * Below lines includes security|error fixes
 */

/**
 * Handle reporting level
 */
error_reporting((APP_ENV === 'development' ? E_ALL : 0));

/**
 * Log errors into a file
 */
ini_set("log_errors", (APP_ENV === 'development'));

/**
 * Display of all other errors
 */
ini_set("display_errors", APP_ENV === 'development');

/**
 * Display of all startup errors
 */
ini_set("display_startup_errors", APP_ENV === 'development');

/**
 * Catch an error message emitted from PHP
 */
ini_set("track_errors", APP_ENV === 'development');

/**
 * Avoid serving non .php files as .php files
 */
ini_set('cgi.fix_pathinfo', 0);

/**
 * Helps mitigate xss
 */
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);

/**
 * Prevents session fixation
 */
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);

/**
 * Fixes files and server encoding
 */
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

/**
 * Some server configurations are missing a date timezone
 */
if (ini_get('date.timezone') == '') {
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
```

When your site goes public, just change the .htaccess env variable to production and all debugging options will disappear. That's the way how i disable such debug options and modules and it works fine.